# How can I disable constraint at table creation time : SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, check-constraints

I want to create an additional table in my database :

```
CREATE TABLE "DEM_TRACE" (
        "Id" NUMERIC(6), 
        "Indice" VARCHAR(3), 
        "Sec_Id" NUMERIC(10), 
        "QUOTE_PART_NUM" NUMERIC(38) DEFAULT 0, 
        "QUOTE_PART_DEN" NUMERIC(38) DEFAULT 1, 
        "OBSERV" NVARCHAR(250), 
        "DATE_CONV_BOR" DATETIME, 
        "DATE_RECE_CONV" DATETIME,
        "CODE_DROIT" NUMERIC(3) DEFAULT 73, 
        "NOM_PA" NVARCHAR(50), 
        WITH NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_QUOTE_PART_1
        CHECK(QUOTE_PART_NUM<=QUOTE_PART_DEN)
)
```

I want  `CK_QUOTE_PART_1` to be disabled after creation of my table. When I added the `WITH NOCHECK` clause before the constraint definition, I'm getting Msg 156 and Msg 319 errors pointing me to line 11 of my code (WITH NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_QUOTE_PART_1) :

```
Message  : Incorrect Syntax near the word WITH
```

What is the problem with my code ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not sure if you need the WITH, can you try to just remove the WITH clause and keep just NOCHECK CONSTRAINT.

Comment: did it and still the same error @mxix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you run this?

```
CREATE TABLE "DEM_TRACE" (
        "Id" NUMERIC(6), 
        "Indice" VARCHAR(3), 
        "Sec_Id" NUMERIC(10), 
        "QUOTE_PART_NUM" NUMERIC(38) DEFAULT 0, 
        "QUOTE_PART_DEN" NUMERIC(38) DEFAULT 1, 
        "OBSERV" NVARCHAR(250), 
        "DATE_CONV_BOR" DATETIME, 
        "DATE_RECE_CONV" DATETIME,
        "CODE_DROIT" NUMERIC(3) DEFAULT 73, 
        "NOM_PA" NVARCHAR(50)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo]."DEM_TRACE"  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_QUOTE_PART_1] CHECK NOT FOR REPLICATION ((QUOTE_PART_NUM<=QUOTE_PART_DEN))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo]."DEM_TRACE" NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_QUOTE_PART_1]
GO
```

Note that I removed all checkings: existing data on creation, inserts, updates and replication.

Comment: I opted for this option after realizing I couldn't disable the constraint in the same script as the one for the creation of my table..Between I didn't understand your last remark :)

Comment: I used Management Studio's table designer to create the check constraint. It offers you those options and I disabled them all. You can see them in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/U80Q9.png

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the hint :)